# LINQ IsAssignableFrom check between two Type[]?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say the following types:

```
public class Object { }
public class GameObject : Object { }
public class Component : Object { }
public class Transform : Component { }
```

And two `Type[]`

```
var t1 = new [] { typeof(Object), typeof(Component) };
var t2 = new [] { typeof(GameObject), typeof(Transform) };
```

And the extension method:

```
Console.Writeline(t1.IsAssignableFrom(t2); // prints true
```

I wrote the method in a basic way:

```
public static bool IsAssignableFrom(this Type[] to, Type[] from)
{
    if (to.Length != from.Length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < to.Length; i++) {
        if (!to[i].IsAssignableFrom(from[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But couldn't write it in a LINQ fashion... - Didn't know what methods to use :s

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're just looking for:

```
return to.Length == from.Length &&
       to.Zip(from, (t, f) => t.IsAssignableFrom(f))
         .All(x => x);
```

The call to [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) here just zips the first elements of both sequences with each other, then the second elements, etc - applying the operation specified as `(t, f) => t.IsAssignableFrom(f)` on each pair. The `All` just checks that the resulting sequence is all true.

Depending on how you're calling this, you *might* want to make it an error for the lengths to be different, instead of just returning `false`:

```
if (to.Length != from.Length)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("...");
}
return to.Zip(from, (t, f) => t.IsAssignableFrom(f))
         .All(x => x);
```

Comment: Wow cool! Thanks for the blazing fast answer! :D - I didn't know about`Zip`

Comment: To be clear, the original code contains `if (to.Length != from.Length) return false;`, and that still needs to be used with this answer. `Zip` stops enumerating when one of the ends is reached.

Comment: @hvd: Ah yes, that's true - adding.

Comment: Yeah for the length miss-match, I was originally intending to throw an exception but I was just testing the method to make sure it works... returning false promotes silent bugs me thinks.

Comment: @vexe: Yup, that was my reaction too.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahh... looks like `Zip` is not available for `Mono`? :( (I code in Unity3d which uses Mono, so...) - do you have an implementation of it in your blogs? :)

Comment: @vexe: It's available in Mono with .NET 4.0 - but for my own implementation: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-35-zip.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
public static bool IsAssignableFrom(this Type[] to, Type[] from)
{
    if (to.Length != from.Length) return false;

    return to.Select((type, idx) => new { type, idx })
             .All((x) => x.type.IsAssignableFrom(from[x.idx]));
}
```

Or:

```
int i = 0;
return to.All(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(from[i++]));
```

Comment: I tried that... But `All` doesn't have an overload that takes an index.

Comment: ah yes, thanks for the alt solution :) - there's a missing "Is" - it's "IsAssignableFrom"